# rest api to return categories information

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I know that there is an api that returns me category information, but it doesn't return category image. I need build my own api to return category image with the information that is returned from the already build.
how can I do so

Answer (score 1):

The Api does return the image of the category. For example I want to get image of category ID 6 than I would,

your_magent_URL/rest/V1/categories/6

The result array look like

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to return all categories with their images?